# text.Substring/text.IndexOf not always returning correct value

Tags: c#

When I am doing a text.Substring it does not always return the correct value depending on where the expression exists within the text I am searching.

For example, I have a text.substring on the contents of a file and I basically want to get the URL that will be specified anywhere in the file but the last part of the URL will always be different. It would be in the format of  `http://myURL:1234/My/Folder/Here`

So here was my code:

```
try
{ 
    string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(textFilePath.Text,filename));

    string FoundName = text.Substring(text.IndexOf("http://", 0) + 7, text.IndexOf(":1234/", 0) - 7);

    if (!listBox4.Items.Contains(FoundName))
    {
        listBox4.Items.Add(FoundName);
    }
}
```

Now if the URL exists at the beginning of the file (position 0) then it works fine.

If it exists anywhere else in the file, such as position 44 the `FoundName` string returns:

`myURL:1234/My/Folder/Here` instead of: `myURL`

If it exists at position 0 then it returns myURL which is correct.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: `vb.net` tag? Really?

Comment: Do you really think it's likely that such a bug would not have been discovered until now? Maybe the parameters to `Substring` have a different meaning than what you think, or your logic to calculate the index and length is wrong.

Comment: why don't you try regex pattern matching ?

Comment: Can you give an example of a working string and an example of a not working string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`string.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a length as its second argument, not an index:

```
int start = text.IndexOf("http://", 0) + 7;
int end = text.IndexOf(":1234/", 0);
string FoundName = text.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
string foundName = text.Substring(
    text.IndexOf("http://") + 7,
    text.IndexOf(":1234/") - text.IndexOf("http://") - 7
    );
```

Or with a temporary variable:

```
int idxDomainStart = text.IndexOf("http://") + 7;
string foundName = text.Substring(idxDomainStart,
    text.IndexOf(":1234/") - idxDomainStart);
```